# Where is the DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been reviewing the MSDN article [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

The above article shows how he is using a `DataTemplate` to display `CustomerViewModel`; But looking at the actual `CustomerView`, there is no `DataContext` set!  How is he calling the `Save` command, when there isn't any `DataContext`, or `ViewModel` wired into the View?

Answer (score 4):

It's set in app.xaml.cs

See Figure 7, where the window's DataContext is set to the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks; I spent wasted time, looking everywhere but there!